# how to add opencv window in window form application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, forms, winapi, opencv

i want to display opencv window in windows application form

i was googling about it i found how to add a simple forme [here](http://www.functionx.com/vcnet/Lesson07.htm)

```
#pragma endregion


        private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object ^  sender, System::EventArgs ^  e)
             {

                 EmotionRec::Baby ^MyBaby = gcnew EmotionRec::Baby;
                 MyBaby->MdiParent = this;
                 MyBaby->Show();
             }
```

Can i add opencv window like baby form !!

Comment: How are you creating your OpenCV window?

Comment: cv::imshow("Adel et Amine", image);
   cv::waitKey(10);

Comment: Your first problem is getting the HWND from the OpenCV window.  OpenCV (AFAIK) doesn't have a function to get the HWND from a NamedWindow, nor does it have a way to create a NamedWindow from an HWND.  This code isn't *hard*, per se, but you will have to modify OpenCV to export a function that returns an HWND from a NamedWindow.